# Magento 2 override Magento_Checkout updatecart.phtml and include js file

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to override updatecart.phtml and put some custom javascript in this file. When i put it in my theme file it goed wel, but how to include the javascript?

I prefer it to do it in my own module and that is working fine for catalog addtocart.phtml. The code is the like below, but for the checkout i can't get it working...

catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Jilco_Plusmin::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Jilco_Plusmin::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app\code\Jilco\Plusmin\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml

```
<?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart" id="box">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty" id="plusmin">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
<div class="control" data-bind="scope: 'qty_change'">

    <button data-bind="click: decreaseQty">-</button>

    <input  data-bind="value: qty()"
            type="number"
            name="qty"
            id="qty"
            maxlength="12"
            title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
            data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
        />
    <button data-bind="click: increaseQty">+</button>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "qty_change": {
                        "component": "Jilco_plusmin/js/view/product/view/qty_change",
                        "defaultQty": <?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
</script>


        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions" id="knop">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'In winkelwagen' ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And of course the javasript in:
app\code\Jilco\Plusmin\view\frontend\web\js\view\product\view\qty_change.js

How to do the same trick for the updatecart?